# Showing past entries on UITextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am writing an app in which I have two `UITextFields`...

1. Starting Text
2. Destination Text

Now once I place values and hit the search or whatever function I want to call, I Want to reuse these values. The app should record and save these values as cache. And should show them when typing or upon a button click. Is that possible to show them just like Dictionary words show up or Which is more preferable `tableView` or `PickerView`? If there is any other please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely use a `UITableView`. A `UIPicherView` is used modally most of the time and not for optional suggestions.

Table view is used in Safari, and a lots of other apps:

[image]

As for how to cache the data, you have lots of options. It also depends on how much data you expect.

One easy way would be to simply use `NSArray`. You can very easily write an `NSArray` to disk in a plist file and read it back when you need it.

Or you could use Core Data, if you expect lots of data and still want high performance. It will be a lot more difficult though to get used to that API if you've never tried it before. Basically you'll need a simple model with one entity called something like `SearchEntry` that has a single property `text`. Then you keep adding new instances to your managed object context and can easily filter the existing values.

Comment: I would suggest a NSPredicate for receiving similar history option for every letter you type. It's amazingly fast to sort your history this way.

Comment: Yes, use `NSPredicate` to filter your entries. This will work both with simple `NSArrays` or `NSFetchRequests` (Core Data).